# NIST эллиптические кривые

Tags: c++, visual-studio, криптография

Для описания кривой в стандарте NIST используется набор из 6 параметров D=(p,a,b,G,n,h), где

p — простое число, модуль эллиптической кривой;
a, b — задают уравнение эллиптической кривой image;
G — точка эллиптической кривой большого порядка. Это означает что если умножать точку на числа меньшие, чем порядок точки, каждый раз будут получаться совершенно различные точки;
n — порядок точки G;
h — параметр, называемый кофактор. Определяется отношением общего числа точек на эллиптической кривой к порядку точки G. Данное число должно быть как можно меньше.

Помогите, пожалуйста, подобрать параметры, которые влезут на C++ в long long.

А то мне предлагают такие:

```
p=6277101735386680763835789423207666416083908700390324961279;
a=-3;
b=2455155546008943817740293915197451784769108058161191238065;
xG=602046282375688656758213480587526111916698976636884684818 (x-координата точки G);
yG=174050332293622031404857552280219410364023488927386650641 (y-координата точки G);
n=6277101735386680763835789423176059013767194773182842284081;
h=1.
```

Но visual studio в шоке от таких значений. Мне просто нужно для демонстрации работы эллиптической криптографии

Comment: Наоборот, вам надо вместо long long использовать длинную арифметику.

Comment: `log(2,10^58)=193` бита. Значит надо использовать длинную арифметику. В плюсах тип `long long` имеет размер только 64 бита.

Comment: Знаю, просто было впадлу её реализовывать. Поэтому хотел найти значения попроще. Если не получится, придется писать

Comment: В Boost есть нужная арифметика, писать не надо.

Comment: Вот тридцатиоднобитная эллиптическая кривая: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45053/32-bit-or-16-bits-elliptic-curves
Точку G и n можно подобрать руками. Правда, для криптографии это плохая кривая, её порядок раскладывается на слишком много простых делителей.